# jQuery - Image flickering on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I have a following code, but when 'previous' or 'next' button shows up, it flickers when I do a `mouseover` event on the buttons.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Portfolio</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/slides.jquery.js"></script>

     </head>
     <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <div id="container">
     <div id="example">
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
            <img src="imgs/test.gif" width="800" height="456" id="gallery_img" border="0"/>
            </div>
        <div class="prevButton" style="visibility:hidden"><a href="#" class="prev"><img src="imgs/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"/></a></div>
        <div class="nextButton" style="visibility:hidden"><a href="#" class="next"><img src="imgs/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"/></a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gallery_img').mouseover(function() {
            $('.prevButton').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('.nextButton').css("visibility", "visible");
        });

        $('#gallery_img').mouseout(function() {
            $('.prevButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('.nextButton').css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
         });
     </script>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Some browsers don't load images if a parent or itself is set to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. If that's the issue you can create dummy, offset DOM elements to make sure it loads (and caches) the images, then remove these DOM elements. Or you can make JS load these images to make sure they're cached using `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'etc.jpg';`

Comment: I am sorry that i don't get it.

Comment: what do you need to do actually?

Comment: I want to display previous/next button when I mouse over the test.gif, but keeps flickering.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers tend not to load sources that don't show in the page, which are hidden by either css rule: `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` - or any of their parents is. This is actually because browsers are trying to preserve space in their caches for each webpage (for speed/efficiency reasons).

Anyway to preload (and make the browser cache) something that is hidden, I can think of 2 solutions: either to load them in elements not hidden but offset (so they're not visible to the user) or take a Javascript approach like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgArr = ['arrow-prev.png','arrow-next.png'];
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'imgs/' + imgArr[i];
        img.onload = function(){}; // this is dummy. not sure if it's needed
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're encountering but you might wanna give it a shot.

**EDIT:** Just reread your code. I think what happens now is, when you mouseover the button, mouse is actually first leaving the image, which makes it trigger the mouseout function (and then back the mouseover function once mouse is moved).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript for this, since you can accomplish the same effect with pure CSS:

```
#slides:hover div.prevButton, #slides:hover div.nextButton
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This would require you to remove the inline styles on the `div`s, since they will override anything in an external stylesheet and anything defined in the `<head>`. You should be able to define a style such as:

```
div.prevButton, div.nextButton
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

HTH.

**EDIT:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEPTk/).

Comment: @user826323 Actually, it does. I didn't quite interpret your markup correctly. See the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this jsfiddle content. It will help you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mangalauwu/5WBhc/1/)

This has used jquery() hover api instead of mouse over.

below is sample code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#b").hide();
     $("#a").hover(
           function(){
              $("#b").show();   
             },
           function(){
            $("#b").hide();  
             }                          
     )

 });
```